# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openDatabase on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, sqflite

Facing this error on running flutter build ios. Sqflite is not reflected in the GeneratedPluginRestraints file after flutter build.
Tried flutter clean, pod update etc nothing works.
Flutter version - 1.7.8 and cocoapods version - 1.6.1
sqflite version in pubspec.yaml - ^1.6.1 in dependency overrides

flutter doctor -v output -

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.7.8, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8 at /Users/oyo/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision d51fd86cdb (6 months ago), 2019-06-21 22:31:55 -0400
    • Engine revision d004bcd4d6
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/oyo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/oyo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor
      --android-licenses

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.1, Build version 11A1027
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 37.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 37.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.7830

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 37.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 192.5728.98

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS • macOS • darwin-x64     • Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132
    • web   • web   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88
```

Comment: In xcode -> Product -> clean and the Product -> build. try and let me know

Comment: @Blasanka got the same error again

Comment: I think you can solve your problem from here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/troubleshooting.md#missingpluginexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run command in your IDE's terminal,

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

There are some android SDK licenses are not accepted. So writing above command will ask you with different licenses to accept with y/n options. Accept all of them to continue your work flow.